# What is ''$n!$ valued function''?

Tags: galois-theory, definition

In ''Galois' theory of algebraic equations'' by James Pierpont I found following definition of $n!$ valued function.

> Let $f(x)=x^n+a_1x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_n$ be an equation to be solved.
> [...] We wish now to form $n!$ valued rational function of the roots.
> To this end we introduce $n$ new variables $u_1$,$u_2$,...,$u_n$ [...]
> Consider the rational function of the roots:
> $V_1=u_1x_1+\cdots+u_nx_n$ ($x_1$,$x_2$,...,$x_n$ are roots of
> $f(x)$). Apply the $n!$ substitutions of the symmetric group
> $S_n=\{s_1=1,s_2,\dots,s_n\}$ to it, and let $s_k$ change $V_1$ into
> $V_k=u_{k_1}x_1+\cdots+u_{k_n}x_n$. Build now equation $$
>  F(t;u_1,\dots,u_n)=(t-V_1)(t-V_2)\cdots(t-V_{n!})=0 $$

I understand that $F(t;u_1,\cdots,u_n)$ is $n!$ valued function here. How to understand that? What are these $n!$ values?

One additional question about semicolon in $(t;u_1,\cdots,u_n)$. Is the reason why semicolon is there is to highlight that variable $t$ has ''different'' status than $u_1$,$u_2$... ?

Comment: Is $F$ the "$n!$-valued function"? Or is $F$ here being built as an intermediate step and what comes next in the text makes the "$n!$-valued function"?  Normally I would expect an $n!$-valued function to be one that produces $n!$ outputs. Like $f(a,b)=(u(a,b),v(a,b),w(a,b))$ is a 3-valued function. And this $F$ is just 1-valued.

Comment: Regarding your semicolon question, yes, I think it's what you suggested. I've seen this sometimes, even in relatively recent (i.e. after late 1950s) publications, and it was probably used more often in Pierpont's time because notion issues were not as precise or widely established as they are now. For instance, one often has to use context to determine whether endpoints of an interval are included. (Starting around 1908 or 1909, I think the term "segment" was sometimes used when endpoints were included.)

Comment: @2'59'2 $F$ is a target of this chapter so i think this is $n!$ valued function. It's not an intermediate product. This is old book and maybe vocabulary or  some definitions changed. Like ''substitution'' of symmetric group instead of permutation.

Comment: Oops, the usage I was thinking of (in the U.S. around mid 1900s to 1910s), due to the wide spread use then of the book [**Introduction to Infinitesimal Analysis. Functions of One Real Variable**](https://archive.org/details/introductiontoi01lenngoog/page/n45/mode/2up) by Veblen/Lennes (1907; see p. 32) is backwards from what I thought --"segment" is when the endpoints are not included, and "interval" is when the endpoints are included.